# Python Classes ('' object has no attribute '')

Tags: python

I defined a class, but when I want to use the function in the class, it gives me an error as follows. Can anybody help me? thank you so much.

```
points = 5

class State:
    def __init__(self, a, b, E_min, E_max, P_s_a, P_s_b, points)):
        self.state = state
        self.isEnd = False
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.E_min = E_min
        self.E_max = E_max
        self.P_s_a = P_s_a
        self.P_s_b = P_s_b
        self.points = points

        y_model = np.zeros(self.points)
        def model(self):
            for j in range(0, points):
                y_model[j] = a * j + b
print(State.model(2,3))
AttributeError: class State has no attribute 'model'
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, the `model()` definition is internal to `__init__()`.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

When you define `model`, it is defined inside `__init__`. To fix this you must change the indentation.

```
points = 5

class State:
    def __init__(self, a, b, E_min, E_max, P_s_a, P_s_b, points)):
        self.state = state
        self.isEnd = False
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.E_min = E_min
        self.E_max = E_max
        self.P_s_a = P_s_a
        self.P_s_b = P_s_b
        self.points = points

        y_model = np.zeros(self.points)
    def model(self):
        for j in range(0, points):
            y_model[j] = a * j + b
print(State.model(2,3))
```